# rails3 asset pipeline and file collisions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I'm updating an existing rails 2 app to rails 3, and having some trouble understanding the asset pipeline. I have read through the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) and as I understand it, files in any of the following directories will resolve to /assets:

- app/assets
- lib/assets
- vendor/assets

and you could access them using helpers...i.e.

```
image_tag('logo.png')
```

But what I don't understand is how collisions are handled? For example, what if there are the following files:

- app/assets/images/logo.png
- lib/assets/images/logo.png

If I go to myapp.com/assets/images/logo.png, which file will be returned? I could check for collisions manually within my app, but this becomes a pain point when using gems that rely on the asset pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what I've found, you can't have duplicate files, as rails will just return the first one found.

This seems like a bit of a design flaw, as a gem may not namespace their own assets

Comment: I've got jQuery bundled by the `jquery-rails` gem. In a separate portion of my Rails project, i would like to use a different version of jQuery, fetched by Bower, without abandoning `jquery-rails` for the rest of the project. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Why not taking advantage of the [`index` manifest](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization) and organize your `app/assets` into decoupled modules? You can then reference to a particular image, `image_tag('admin/logo.png')`, and get for free your UI codebase organised in a more meaningful way. You could even promote a complex component, such as Single Page Application into it's own module and reuse it from different parts of the app.

Let's say you app is composed out of three modules: the public side, an admin UI and, e.g., a CRM to let your agents track the selling process at your company:

```
app/assets/
├── coffeescripts
│   ├── admin
│   │   ├── components
│   │   ├── index.coffee
│   │   └── initializers
│   ├── application
│   │   ├── components
│   │   ├── index.sass
│   │   └── initializers
│   └── crm
│       ├── components
│       ├── index.sass
│       └── initializers
├── images
│   ├── admin
│   ├── application
│   └── crm
└── stylesheets
    ├── admin
    │   ├── components
    │   └── index.sass
    ├── application
    │   ├── components
    │   └── index.sass
    └── crm
        ├── components
        └── index.sass

21 directories, 6 files
```

Don't forget to update your `application.rb` so they will be precompiled properly:

```
  config.assets.precompile = %w(admin.js application.js crm.js 
                                admin.css application.css crm.css)
```